# A white yellowish filling in my sausage

Tags: sausages, filling, hot-dog

What is the filling in my sausage? I am thinking fat.

[image: sausage filling]

What do you think?

Comment: could it be cheese filled?

Comment: Looks like cheese to me...at least that's what I'd tell myself.

Comment: Does it extend all the way through the length?